# Multiplication of Number Properties in class returns Nan

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I was trying out the below sample code for JavaScript Class in chrome and i am getting output as Nan even though the datatype of both properties is Number.

```
class Sample
{
constructor(height,width)
{
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
}

calcArea()
{
    console.log ("Height : " + this.height + " Type : " + typeof this.height);
    console.log ("Width : " + this.width + " Type : " + typeof this.width);
    console.log( this.height * this.Width);
}
} 
var objSample = new Sample(10,20);
objSample.calcArea();
```

Please find below the output i got in console. Thanks

```
Height : 10 Type : number
Width : 20 Type : number
NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a casing error in your calculation. You do `this.height * this.Width` when it should be `this.height * this.width`